# SQLite IN operator with multiple conditions in for loop

Tags: sqlite, for-loop, sql-in

I have the following:

```
x = ['dat1','dat2']
y = ['M','F']

for x,y in zip(x,y):
    conn.execute('''
                create table %s as
                select sex as sex
                from raw
                where sex in (?)
                '''%(x),(y )
                )

conn.commit()
```

How do set the for loop/list to capture both M and F strings along with M and F individually without resorting to joins? I've tried various lists such as this `y = ['M','F','"M","F"']` but they don't work (I included 'dat3' in x as well). Is `format()` needed?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with the `LIKE` operator:

```
x = ['dat1','dat2','dat3']
y = ['M%','F%','%']

for x,y in zip(x,y):
    conn.execute('''
                create table %s as
                select sex as sex
                from raw
                where sex like ?
                '''%(x),(y, )
                )

conn.commit()
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining it